# NFT with Anchor lang on Solona program

Tags: anchor, nft

I'm looking to make a game on solona. Each player will have multiple characters, so I want to use NFT to store character information like Ethereum's ERC721. Can I use lang neo to create NFTs and distribute them to players?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with ERC721 or lang neo, but on Solana you can use a PDA to save extra player data and use the mint of the NFT as a seed like so:

```
#[account( 
    init,
    payer = signer,
    space = 800,
    seeds = [b"player".as_ref(), signer.key().as_ref(), nftMint.key().as_ref()],
    bump,
)]
pub player: Account<'info, PlayerData>,

#[account]
pub struct PlayerData {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub board: BoardData,
    pub score: u32,
    pub game_over: bool,
    pub new_tile_level: u32,
    pub xp: u32,
    pub level: u32,
etc...
}
```

Like this you can have one game state per NFT for example or save things like xp and level etc.
Here is a complete on chain game which uses this technic:
https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-2048

Comment: Hello, thank a lot!

Comment: Excited to see what you are building :)